# Add list of list to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of list as follows:

```
[[7, 4],
 [],
 [8],
 [6, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9],
 [],
 [4, 8, 3, 6, 6, 4],
 [],
 [8, 3, 3],
 [],
 [4, 8, 3, 4]]
```

I would like to add this to an existing Pandas data frame as a new column where each row will get a list. For example, first row of the new column will contain [7,4], second column [], third column [8] etc.

Can someone assist on how to add this list of list to a data frame?

Comment: Use `df['b'] = L` only.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565376/insert-list-of-lists-into-single-column-of-pandas-df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you DataFrame is called `df` and you list (with the lists) is called `li`, you can do this with:

```
df['new_column'] = li
```

But in order to do this, your dataframe has to have the same length as the list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([l for l in range(10)], columns = ['existing_column'])
li = [[7, 4],
      [],
      [8],
      [6, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9],
      [],
      [4, 8, 3, 6, 6, 4],
      [],
      [8, 3, 3],
      [],
      [4, 8, 3, 4]
     ]
df['new_column'] = li
```

Comment: This is what I was trying but by mistake had it inside a loop. Putting it outside works fine.