# How can I insert element in list into pandas dataframe creating new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of list,

```py
[ ['hello'], ['world', 'foo'], ['bar', 'bye', 'python'] ]
```

How can I insert its element into existing dataframe with new column?

```
# current
# df
index language
 a     python
 b      java
 c       c#

# expecting output
# df
index language slug
 a     python   ['hello']
 b      java    ['world', 'foo']
 c       c#     ['bar', 'bye', 'python']
```

Comment: Have you tried `df.assign(slug=my_list)`?

Comment: Just `df['slug'] = [['hello'], ['world', 'foo'], ['bar', 'bye', 'python']]` would work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert list of lists into single column of pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565376/insert-list-of-lists-into-single-column-of-pandas-df)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Very close! But Dishin 's solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
df["columns_name"]=[[ ['hello'], ['world', 'foo'], ['bar', 
'bye', 'python']]
```

You shold have equal number of rows in your existing_dataframe for eg here you insert 3 rows of data but you shoud also have 3 rows in existing_dataframe